# aligning a table on left doesn't work by CSS, but works by HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem with a when I want to change an inline style for a table to a style defined in CSS. My goal is to align this table to the left of the page.

Aligns correctly to the left:
HTML:

```
<table class="box-table" style="margin-left: 0px">
<tr>
     <td>table content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.box-table
{
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Doesn't align to the left (aligns to the center of the page)
HTML:

```
<table class="box-table">
<tr>
     <td>table content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.box-table
{
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

The only change I did was moving the margin-left -property from the HTML- to the CSS-code. Any idea why tis happens?

Comment: There may be a more specific rule that places an "auto" margin on the table at hand. Have you tried inspecting the table with a developer toolbar yet? (Firebug, IE Dev toolbar, etc) Probably it will tell you what the left-margin is for the table, and where it comes from.

Comment: As Jeroen says, there is surely some other rule in play here. You code above should not display different results - as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/BDRKZ/

Comment: @Jeroen, thanks for the help. By this tip I found out that this class was declared 2 times in my CSS, which had conflicting values about the margin-left -property. I found it out by using the IE Developer Tools. Simply didn't look at this problem with an inspector tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that this class was declared 2 times in my CSS, which had conflicting values about the margin-left -property.